# Making a Java Swing game a browser based game

Tags: java, browser-based-games, swing

I have made a game in Java using Swing for the GUI.
It is a network game relying on the client-server model.
Basically the game is a turned-based chess-like game. It has a connection menu, game searching screen and a game screen.
Graphics are simple, it's just rendering a board with pieces in 2D.

I want to make this game a browser game.
At first I thought of Java EE. Making the game an applet and embed it in a JSP but it doesn't seem to be a good solution.
So I did some research looking for open source solutions.
I came across the Play Framework that allow to write web apps in Java. Play seems good but I dont know if I can reuse my Swing GUI with it.
I also encountered the libGDX framework.
Finally, some say that HTML5 is the way to god for a 2D browser games, combined with the framework Phaser.

Which technology would fit for this kind of game and should I go for ?
I would like to stick with Java if possible.

Any advice or solution suggestion would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is off-topic, since we do not answer questions asking "which technology to use?".

Comment: Thanks @Tyyppi_77 for your reply. I didn't want to generate discussion over the technologies. Where am I supposed to ask this kind of question ?

Answer (score 1):

It used to be possible to deploy Java applications on the web in form of java applets. But several security holes were found in the technology. So the browser vendors no longer support it.

If you want to turn your game into a browser game, then you won't get around to reimplement it from scratch as a HTML5/Javascript application. Phaser is just one of many game development frameworks on top of Javascript. Which one is the best for you and your game is a matter of personal preference.